# Is it possible to train a neural network with 3 inputs and 12 outputs?

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, neural-architecture-search, thought-vectors

The selection of experimental data includes a set of vectors of different dimensions. The input is a 3-dimensional vector, and the output is a 12-dimensional vector. The sample size is 120 pairs of input 3-dimensional and output 12-dimensional vectors.

Is it possible to train such a neural network (in MATLAB)? Which structure of the neural network is best suited for this?

Comment: Hello, could you provide an overview of the data and/or problem you're trying to solve? Without such information I can not give you a full answer.

Comment: Hello, I do direct kinematics of the robot. The input 3-dimensional vector consists of the rotation angles of the corresponding drive. The working body of the robot is a triangular platform. As the output, I record the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle in the base coordinate system (we get three 3-dimensional vectors = only 9 coordinates) and three angular velocities along the x, y and z axes. In total, a 12-dimensional output vector is obtained.

Comment: I need to approximate data using a neural network, i.e. train it when applying the appropriate 3-dimensional vector to produce the corresponding 12-dimensional vector. I have a training database.

Comment: Please see my adjusted starting communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you, you can setup Dense Neural Networks to have any size inputs or outputs (simple proof is to imagine a single layer NN with no activation is just a linear transform and given input dim $n$ and output dim $m$, it's just a matrix of $n$ x $m$, trivially this works though with any number of hidden layers)

The better question is *should you?*. In all honesty, it depends on the data that you have, but, usually, with only 120 examples you'll either overfit completely or do relatively well if the true solution is a very simple function, but, in general, in the common situations where that isn't the case I find myself more likely or not using Bayesian approaches, so I can actually consider confidence (with little data, this is really nice)

Comment: Are there any recommendations for choosing the number of layers and neurons in them, as well as activation functions?

Comment: @AndrewSol For the most part no, usually grid searches or previous empirical results are used.

Comment: @ mshlis - Re: Please see my adjusted starting message.

Answer (score 1):

The perceptron convergence theorem states that any architecture will lead to a correlation between the data.

Yes, you can!