# How do I determine the best neural network architecture for a problem with 3 inputs and 12 outputs?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, feedforward-neural-networks, neural-architecture-search, thought-vectors

This post continues the topic in the following post: 
 [Is it possible to train a neural network with 3 inputs and 12 outputs?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17553/2444).

I conducted several experiments in MATLAB and selected those neural networks that best approximate the data.

Here is a list of them:

- Cascade-forward backpropagation
- Elman backpropagation
- Generalized regression
- Radial basis (exact fit)

I did not notice a fundamental difference in quality, except for Elman's backpropagation, which had a higher error than the rest.

How to justify the choice of the structure of the neural network in this case?